# How can I fill a DataFrame column with a list of e.g. 2 values in Pandas Python?

Tags: python

That question is probably quite simple, but I am a python beginner:

I want to create a DataFrame column for a given DataFrame = df and fill it with a list of values. It's absolutely clear to me how I fill it with one value:

```
df["xyz"] = 1
```

but this doesn't work:

```
df["xyz"] = [0,1]
```

I want to fill the column with 0,1,0,1,0,1...

Do you know how to solve that? Also for longer lists?

Comment: Don't forget that documentation is readily available - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) & [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> df['xyz'] = list(islice(cycle([0, 1]), len(df)))
```